# Why is ~b=-6 if b=5?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, twos-complement

I can't get the 2-complement calculation to work.

I know C compiles ~b that would invert all bits to -6 if b=5. But why?

int b=101, inverting all bits is 010 then for 2 complement's notation I just add 1 but that becomes 011 i.e. 3 which is wrong answer.

How should I calculate with bit inversion operator ~?

Comment: `~(~a) == a` for any `a`, because the `~` operator is self-inverse. I don't really know how to explain why that is, other than to observe that `~` operates on each bit independently, and it is certainly self-inverse for a single bit.

Comment: " inverting all bits is 010" -- No, inverting all bits yields 111111...010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~b` is not a 2-complement operation. It is a bitwise NOT operation. It just inverts every bit in a number, therefore `~b` is unequal to `-b`.

Examples:

```
b = 5
binary representation of b:  0000 0000 0000 0101
binary representation of ~b: 1111 1111 1111 1010
~b = -6

b = 17
binary representation of b:     0000 0000 0001 0001
binary representation of ~b:    1111 1111 1110 1110
~b = -18
binary representation of ~(~b): 0000 0000 0001 0001
~(~b) = 17
```

Comment: OK but you ARE using 2-complement when you say that 1111111111111010 = - 6 because you are inverting all bits and adding one two get which negative number this is and this is the part I was wondering about. I hope you can verify that I seem to understand how it works.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz: Per definition of 2-complement, -x == ~x+1. Therefore, 11..1010+1 == 11..1011 == -5. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes but only slowly could I follow the steps that you are actually inverting all bits and adding one which is the 2-complement. What you don't do is the mistake I was doing: Adding one to the first invertion. And it helps that this is a general formula -x=~x+1

Answer (score 7):

Actually, here's how 5 is usually represented in memory (16-bit integer):

```
0000 0000 0000 0101
```

When you invert 5, you flip all the bits to get:

```
1111 1111 1111 1010
```

That is actually -6 in decimal form. I think in your question, you were simply flipping the last three bits only, when in fact you have to consider all the bits that comprise the integer.

Comment: And 1111 1111 1111 1010 is -6 in decimal form from inverting all the bits and adding one which is called 2-complement notation(?) so there are in fact two inversions performed, one of which is used to find out which number the binary number is that starts with a 1 and therefore is negative.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with `b = 101 (5)` is that you have chosen one too few binary digits.

```
        binary | decimal  
~101 = 010     | ~5 = 2  
~101 + 1 = 011 | ~5 + 1 = 3
```

If you choose 4 bits, you'll get the expected result:

```
          binary | decimal  
~0101 = 1010     | ~5 = -6  
~0101 + 1 = 1011 | ~5 + 1 = -5
```

With only 3 bits you can encode integers from -4 to +3 in 2's complement representation.
With 4 bits you can encode integers from -8 to +7 in 2's complement representation.

-6 was getting truncated to 2 and -5 was getting truncated to 3 in 3 bits. You needed at least 4 bits.

And as others have already pointed out, `~` simply inverts all bits in a value, so, `~~17` = `17`.

Answer (score 3):

`~` simply inverts all the bits of a number:

```
~(~a)=17 if a=17
~0...010001 = 1...101110 ( = -18 )
~1...101110 = 0...010001 ( = 17 )
```

You need to add 1 only in case you want to negate a number (to get a 2-s complement) i.e. get -17 out of 17.

Answer (score 1):

`~b + 1 = -b`

So:

`~(~b)` equals `~(-b - 1)` equals `-(-b - 1) -1` equals `b`

In fact, `~` reverse all bits, and if you do `~` again, it will reverse back.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't get the 2-completement calculation to work.
>   I know C compiles ~b that whould invert all bits to -6 if b=5. But why?

Because you are using two's complement. Do you know what two's complement is?

Lets say that we have a byte variable (signed char). Such a variable can have the values from 0 to 127 or from -128 to 0.

Binary, it works like this:

```
0000 0000  // 0
...
0111 1111  // 127
1000 0000  // -128
1000 0001  // -127
...
1111 1111  // -1
```

Signed numbers are often described with a [circle](http://www.yournotes.com/notes/fall98/cse271/cse271c_101298.jpg).

If you understand the above, then you understand why ~1 equals -2 and so on.

Had you used one's complement, then ~1 would have been -1, because one's complement uses a signed zero. For a byte, described with one's complement, values would go from 0 to 127 to -127 to -0 back to 0.

Comment: I think I know 2 complement's notation and was using it and therefore it did not work. Now ~1 equals -2 because ...001 inverted is ...110 which by two complement's notation is -2 since inverting all bits and adding one equals -2!(?)

Comment: @NickRosencrantz 110 is -2 in two's complement, because that's how two's complement is defined, as I described above. You don't "add" anything. You are making an assumption that the binary representation of signed numbers follows some sort of mathematical logic, it doesn't work that way. Someone has simply defined: "this is how signed numbers are represented on a binary level, deal with it".

Answer (score 0):

you declared b as an integer. That means the value of b will be stored in 32 bits and the complement (~) will take place on the 32 bit word and not the last 3 bits as you are doing.

```
    int b=5 // b in binary: 0000 0000 0000 0101  
    ~b // ~b in binary: 1111 1111 1111 1010 = -6 in decimal
```

The most significant bit stores the sign of the integer (1:negetive 0:positive) so 1111 1111 1111 1010 is -6 in decimal.
Similarly:

```
    b=17 // 17 in binary 0000 0000 0001 0001  
    ~b // = 1111 1111 1110 1110 = -18
```